Domain of the inverse of a compact operator on Hilbert Space
i have the following problem:
Let $A$ be an integral operator defined on $L^2([-1, 1])$ by:
$
(Af)(x) = \int_{-1}^1 |x - y| f(y) \, dy.$
Consider the operator $T$ as the inverse of $A$, that is, $T = A^{-1}$. What is the domain of T? What's the adjoint operator of T?
I've tried to find the image of the compact integral operator, but i can't find all boundary conditions to properly define T. Thank you so much.

Hint: Note that $Af$ is just the convolution of $f$ with the identity map on $[-1,1]$. Use the fact the Fourier transform of a convolution is just the product of Fourier transforms and try to work in the Fourier domain.

Im not sure $A$ will be invertible. By C-S, $A$ maps $L^{2}([-1,1])$ to itself.  However, it is very easy to show that a compact operator in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space cannot be invertible i.e $0 \in \sigma(A)$.

@AnCar how do you carry out a Fourier transform on $[-1,1]$?

@Evil Witch I think the question is about the inverse as a not-necessarily bounded but densely defined operator.

oh, clearly. My bad

@Lieven You can interpret those as functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and the Fourier Transform is a unitary operator between $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ into itself.

If you interpret them as functions on the real line, isn't there a cutoff involved after convolution with $|x|$ ?

Edited: the original answer had a spurious factor $x$
We have
$$(Af)(x)=x\int_{y=-1}^xf(y)dy-\int_{y=-1}^xyf(y)dy-x\int_{y=x}^1f(y)dy+\int_{y=x}^1yf(y)dy$$
All four integrands on the RHS are Lebesgue integrable on the interval $[-1,1].$ The Lebesgue version of the fundamental theorem of integral calculus then guarantees that these four integrals are almost everywhere differentiable as a function of $x,$ and the derivative is (a.e.) the integrand evaluated at $x$ (with a minus sign where $x$ is the lower limit of the integral). Thus the RHS itself is a.e. differentiable and
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left((Af)(x)\right)=xf(x)+\int_{y=-1}^xf(y)dy-xf(x)+xf(x)-\int_{y=x}^1f(y)dy-xf(x)$$
Four of these six terms cancel and the remaining integrals are an a.e. differentiable function of $x$ for the same reason as above, with
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left((Af)(x)\right)=2f(x)$$
This means that the range of $A$ consists of functions that are twice differentiable almost everywhere and their second derivative is square integrable. The inverse is half of the second derivative operator.
For the appropriate boundary conditions note that the functions in the range of $A$ are continuously differentiable everywhere, and by partial integration (twice)
$$\int_{-1}^1f''(y)g(y)dy=f'(1)g(1)-f'(-1)g(-1)-f(1)g'(1)+f(-1)g'(-1)+\int_{-1}^1f(y)g''(y)dy$$
so the inverse of $A$ would become self-adjoint, for example, by restricting its domain to functions that evaluate to zero at the end points (Dirichlet boundary conditions) or alternatively to functions whose derivatives are zero at the end points (Neumann boundary conditions), or even some kind of linear combination that treats the left boundary differently from the right boundary. Without any restriction on the domain of the inverse, its adjoint has a smaller domain where both the functions themselves and their first derivatives evaluate to zero at the end points.

second derivative? why can you take that?

Using the fundamental theorem of integral calculus (Lebesgue version) twice.

sorry, I still don't get this. Can you be more explicit with why the RHS summands are twice differentiable for an arbitrary $f \in L^2$?

Ok, edited (among other reasons like an obvious calculation error :-) ) to address that concern.

Could i for example take:$ g(-1)+g(1)=0 $ and $g'(1)=g'(-1)$ as boundary conditions? The second one is true, but the first one is true only if the integral of g is 0.

A domain with those specific boundary conditions would not make $A^{-1}$ a symmetric operator, as can be seen from the example $f(y)=y^3,$ $g(y)=y.$ Both functions are in your domain, yet the expression $f'(1)g(1)-f'(-1)g(-1)-f(1)g'(1)+f(-1)g'(-1)$ is nonzero. I do not understand your remark about the integral of $g.$ Note that if you take truly periodic boundary conditions ($g(-1)=g(1)$ and $g'(-1)=g'(1)$) then symmetry is restored - in fact the inverse operator becomes self-adjoint, but that requires a little more work.

For simplicity, I will use the Fourier transform defined as $\hat{f} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{2\pi ikx}f(x)dx$.
First note that if $f \in L^{2}[-1,1]$, then $|Af(x)| \leq \int_{[-1,1]}(|x|+|y|)f(y)dy\leq 2\int_{[-1,1]}|f(y)dy|\leq 2\sqrt{2}||f||_{2}$ and hence, $\int_{[-1,1]}|Af(x)|^2dx \leq 8||f||^2_2\cdot 2 = 16||f||_{2}^2<\infty$ and thus, $A$ maps $L^2[-1,1]$ into itself. Hence we can take the Fourier transform (since is a unitary operator acting in $L^2$).
Now, $B\equiv \mathscr{F}A\mathscr{F}^{-1}: L^2([-1,1])\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a multiplication operator, since $\mathscr{F}A\mathscr{F}^{-1}f  = \mathscr{F}((\mathscr{F}^{-1}f)*|x|) =\hat{|x|}f.$ However, a simple calculation shows
$$\hat{\cdot}(k) = \int_{[-1,1]}e^{2\pi ikx}|x|dx =\cos(2\pi k)\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi ik}+\dfrac{1}{2\pi^2 k^2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{2\pi^2 k^2} \quad k \in \mathbb{R}.$$
You can conclude that the spectrum of the multiplication operator $B$ is $essRan(\hat{\cdot})$.
I think you can continue from here.

If you apply the (inverse) Fourier transform to a function in $L^2[-1,1]$ then the domain of the resulting function is larger than the interval. Taking the integral from the problem statement, which is limited to the interval, is then no longer a pure convolution and therefore the end result of the second Fourier transform is not equal to the original function multiplied by the absolute value function.

you're right, damn!
